# Unknown provider: accordionDirectiveProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion, jquery-ui-sortable

Could anybody help me to figure out where my mistake is? I used [**this example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/x4jxAfIaqeQXfTmsj3r3?p=preview) that to build sortable accordion on my page. Example works well, but I've put this code to my app and got this error

> > angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown
> >     provider: accordionDirectiveProvider
> >     http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=accordionDirectiveProvider
> >         at http://localhost:63342/myapp%202.0/libs/angular/angular.js:68:20
> >         at http://localhost:63342/myapp%202.0/libs/angular/angular.js:4502:27
> >         at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:63342/myapp%202.0/libs/angular/angular.js:4655:53)
> >         at Object.decorator (http://localhost:63342/myapp%202.0/libs/angular/angular.js:4577:49)
> >         at http://localhost:63342/myapp%202.0/js/app/app.js:56:18
> >         at Object.invoke (http://localhost:63342/myapp%202.0/libs/angular/angular.js:4709:31)
> >         at runInvokeQueue (http://localhost:63342/myapp%202.0/libs/angular/angular.js:4602:49)
> >         at http://localhost:63342/myapp%202.0/libs/angular/angular.js:4611:25
> >         at forEach (http://localhost:63342/myapp%202.0/libs/angular/angular.js:321:34)
> >         at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/myapp%202.0/libs/angular/angular.js:4592:13)
> >     http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…localhost%3A63342%2Fmyapp%25202.0%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4592%3A13)

As I can see from this line something wrong with my provider

```
http://localhost:63342/myapp%202.0/js/app/app.js:56:18 at Object.invoke 

 .config(['$provide', function ($provide){
    $provide.decorator('accordionDirective', function($delegate) {
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        directive.replace = true;
        return $delegate;
    });
}])
```

But however I clear my code from this provider, accordion stop working. Where is my mistake? I apologize but cannot catch this error in the plunker so put my code below

```
    (function () {

    window.app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.sortable', 'ngSanitize',
        'ngTouch',
        'ui.grid',
        'ui.grid.exporter',
        'ui.grid.selection',
        'ui.grid.pagination',

        'ui.grid.saveState',
        'ui.grid.cellNav',
        'ui.grid.resizeColumns',
        'ui.grid.moveColumns',
        'ui.grid.pinning',
        'ui.grid.grouping',
        'ui.grid.autoResize',

        'ui.grid.edit',
        'ui.grid.rowEdit'
    ])

        .run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
                $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
            });
        }])

        .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
        }])

        .config(['$routeProvider',
            function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    title: " ",
                    controller: 'homeCtrl'
                })
                .when('/page', {
                    title: 'GRID',
                    templateUrl: 'html/pages/grid.html',
                    controller: 'gridCtrl'
                })
                .when('/designer', {
                    title: 'Design Grid',
                    templateUrl: 'html/pages/designer.html',
                    controller: 'designerCtrl'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
            });
        }])

    .config(['$provide', function ($provide){
        $provide.decorator('accordionDirective', function($delegate) {
            var directive = $delegate[0];
            directive.replace = true;
            return $delegate;
        });
    }])

        .filter('makeUppercase', function () {
            return function (item) {
                var space = item.replace(/\./g, " ");
                var result = space.replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1");
                return result.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + result.slice(1)
            };
        })

}());
```

html

```
 <uib-accordion  ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="panels">
                <uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="panel in panels">
                <uib-accordion-heading>
                    <div class="handle"><i class="fa fa-arrows pull-left"></i></div>
                    <span class="panel-title-left">{{panel.heading}}</span>
                    <i class="caret pull-right"></i>
                </uib-accordion-heading>
                   <div ng-include=" panel.url "></div>
            </uib-accordion-group>
            </uib-accordion>
```

Comment: Unless it is just a typo somewhere, things seem fine to me. 
Are you sure that this accordion module is installed and included in your index file?

Comment: @Riv What do you mean by accordion module? this accordion directive doesn't need any dependencies https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be if you use uib-tools 1.+. In latest version they have changed the name of directive from 'accordion' to 'uibAccordion', so probably you have to use 'uibAccordionDirective'. See example

```
  .config(['$provide', function ($provide){
         $provide.decorator('uibAccordionDirective', function($delegate) {
                var directive = $delegate[0];
                directive.replace = true;
                return $delegate;
            });
        }])
```